# How to hide wifi/Bluetooth/battery icons from top right corner in status bar/top bar?

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, icons, battery

Basically I want to hide all icons from top right bar. Whenever we enable WiFi, Bluetooth or whatever available in Ubuntu Status bar it shows an icon of that function in top right corner of the screen. I want to hide Those icons even my WiFi or other things are open. Kindly help me. I am using Ubuntu 23.10 latest version.

Comment: On the `dash-to-panel` extension there is an option to hide the **System Menu**

Comment: have you tried just-perfection gnome shell extension?

Comment: dash-to-panel and just perfection both extentions are unavalale

Answer (score 0):

I found extension [Quick Setting Tweaker](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5446/quick-settings-tweaker/)  that allows you to disable unnecessary icons. I checked it on Fedora with Gnome 45, it works, but the description of this feature says "This feature is unstable sometimes", so you have to be careful